# How to specify IP country on TOR (windows)?

Tags: tor

I can change that easily on linux using torrc file, but cannot find the option on tor browser for windows.

It looks like it can be done via "vidalia": but how to access that ?
I cannot find any vidalia on my TOR browser

Answer (score 8):

The Tor Browser Bundle on Windows includes a `torrc` file which should be located at `\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc` under where you install Tor Browser to.

You can add or change the `ExitNodes` option in the file to the country you want to use (e.g. `{US}`).

If you're using the Expert Bundle, it does not ship with a `torrc` file, but you can specify one when you run Tor from the command line:

```
tor.exe -f C:/path/to/torrc
```

Or just specify your options from the command line:

```
tor.exe -f C:/path/to/torrc ExitNodes {US}
```

Get the default copy of `torrc` from [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in).

Comment: It would be great to have a button to directly choose the exit country or even the whole route.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.  
Although I had to manually copy 'geoip' files to AppData/Roaming/tor.

Comment: weird. I  tried tor.exe -f C:/path/to/torrc ExitNodes {US} 
tor launched and opened two tabs 1. http://{us}/
& 2. http://exitnodes/

Comment: @CodingMatters This probably means you weren't talking to the tor.exe daemon from the expert bundle but instead talked to the Tor Browser's startup script which is a wrapper to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The country code list is available here -> http://startup-bootcamp.fr/liste-des-codes-des-pays-tor/

You can choose or exclude specific country in your torrc configuration file.