# Tor configuration file location - Windows

Tags: windows, tor

I've installed the Tor Expert Bundle on Windows 10 and I don't find the `torrc` file. What is its default location?

If its default location is inside `C:\Users\user\...` it may be problematic because my username includes accents.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you notice [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512989/how-to-specify-ip-country-on-tor-windows)? One answer suggests the config file is on a specific path under the installation folder

Comment: OK thanks. So with the Expert Bundle there is not torrc file, but we can specify one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a torrc file with the Expert Bundle, but we can specify one.